# Trying to access array offset of type bool at line 128

Tags: minecraft, bool

Строка ошибки:

```
$member = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM MEMBERS WHERE Region = '" . $result['Region'] . "' AND Name = '$username'")->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);
```

Comment: с вероятностью 99% у вас в переменной `$result` значение `false`. Не спрашивайте почему, из текущего кода это не ясно.

Comment: Поменять его на true ?

Comment: ну вряд ли оно от этого станет массивом с одним из ключей `Region`

Comment: что делать тогда

Comment: смотреть код получения `$result` и находить ошибку

Comment: У вас есть вконтакте?